# jQuery change action from another change action

Tags: jquery

I have the next code:

js:

```
    $('[id^="check-"]').change(function(){
        var new_id = this.id.replace(/check/, 'new'),
            real_id = this.id.replace(/check/, 'real');
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#'+real_id).val($('#'+new_id).text());
        } else {
            $('#'+real_id).val(0);
        }
    });
```

html:

```
<tr>
  <td><span id="new-1">2</span></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="real-1" id="real-1" value="0"></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" class="card" id="check-1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><span id="new-2">7</span></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="real-2" id="real-2" value="0"></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" class="card" id="check-2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><span id="new-3">4</span></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="real-3" id="real-3" value="0"></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" class="card" id="check-3"></td>
</tr>
```

The main idea: take the text from `new-*` and put it into `real-*` inbox when you click on related `check-*` checkbox.

Now I want to add another checkbox that mass executes this operation for all the elements.
I tried it:

```
    $('#main-checkbox').change(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('.card').attr('checked', true);
        } else {
            $('.card').attr('checked', false);
        }

    });
```

But it does not work. Why?
How can I start the `change` action for all those checkouts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing field values (including checked status) via JavaScript doesn't trigger change events, but you can call the `.change()` method explicitly. Your function can also be simplified - you don't really need the if/else structure:

```
$('#main-checkbox').change(function(){
    $('.card').attr('checked', this.checked).change();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4qs4d/

Note that `$(this).is(':checked')` is just a slow way of saying `this.checked`. Also, if you are using jQuery 1.6 or later you should use the [`.prop()` method](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) rather than `.attr()`.